# Charges on Azure cosmos db lifetime free account

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have created a Cosmos DB lifetime free account,(not the Azure free account), with a limit of 400 RU/s and 5 GB storage limit. I have created a DB with Mongo DB API and set the provisioned throughput as 400 RU/s.

Currently, the storage is around 1.70 GB and the index storage is around 80 MB.

When I look at the metrics I see that sometimes consumed RU is in the range of 4K over the period of time and I am getting billed at around $3 per day, even though my account is free.

So, I have a couple of questions:

1. Is there anything I need to do, like limit the RU on the database, to make sure that my web application does not consume more than 400 RU/s and throttle the request? This is really a demo application and will prefer slow queries over getting charged.
2. Are there any gotchas with Cosmos DB free account that I need to be aware of? Like, are there are settings I need to do to make sure that I don't get changed for Cosmos DB free account?

Any pointers/tips for using Cosmos DB will be helpful.

Comment: Is the account provisioned for autoscale? How are you able to consume more throughput than what is provisioned?

Comment: @MarkBrown, that's a good pointer. The default option was to auto-scale with 4000 RU/s. So now I look at it, that could be the reason for going over the provisioned throughput.

Comment: You will be billed only for the portion that went above 400RU/s. If you set the "Provision database throughput " to 400 RU/s at your database level, you will be throttled to that limit. Also, you should have only 1 DB in 1 region. No geo-replication.